# Filter Search Craft 3

Tags: craft3, jquery

Does anyone know or have a solution for a live search filter on the frontend for Craft.  I can muscle through putting something together but if you have used something that is friendly enough, would like to see the solution for Craft.

Comment: i'm not clear what live search filter is

Comment: I probably should have used the words auto-complete, shows my lack of dev :) . Like this example http://easyautocomplete.com/

Comment: if you google for "search ahead" and "incremental search" you might be able to find a plugin (or craft plugin) to do this for you

Comment: I did all that search stuff and came up with zip.  Might have to put it together myself.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this article will help! https://nystudio107.com/blog/autocomplete-search-with-the-element-api-vuejs